# Removing the enumeration of align text

Tags: numbering, align

I want to remove the number next to the aligned text produced by this code:

```
\begin{align}
U & =c^\intercal G_1\\
V & =b^\intercal G_2,\notag
\end{align}
```

Which displays as follows:
[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can use the `align*` environment instead of `align`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Can you explain to me what the main difference is between align* and align? I would happily accept your answer if you post it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with other environments that come with the `amsmath` package, `align` numbers each line of the equation, while the "starred" version `align*` does not print numbers at the end of each line. (Thus if you use `align*`, there's no need for the `\notag` in the second line.)

The command `\notag`, which is used in your example, instructs TeX ***not*** to number a line in which it is issued. That's why you have an equation number in the first line but not the second. In your case, another possibility is to use `\notag` on the first line (before the line break `\\`) as well. But the use of `align*` is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can read [here](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) about align environment and equations numbering.

Comment: Erh, that article is about `eqnarray`, not really relevant here. This might be a better choice http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf (the `ams` guide). BTW: I wrote the article you refer to ;-)